# Unable to call external JSON in Morris Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, servlets

I have external JSON file in the below format :--

```
{"data":[["A","2256","2182","74"],["CANADA","726","709","17"],  ["E","1571","1519","52"],["F","4005","3935","70"],["G","1083","1068","15"],["J","759","755","4"],["L","1022","1000","22"],["S","8665","8514","151"]]}
```

And my morris-bar.js is

```
$(function() {
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-year',
    data: [{
        y: 'A',a: 2086,c: 2001, b: 85},
      { y: 'C', a: 690,c: 680,  b: 10},
      { y: 'E', a: 1472,c: 1428,b: 48},
      { y: 'F', a: 3380,c: 3724,b: 106},
      { y: 'C', a: 1009,c: 980, b: 29 },
      { y: 'J', a: 727, c: 724, b: 3  }, 
      { y: 'L', a: 967, c: 957, b: 10 },
      { y: 'S', a: 8157,c: 7965,b: 192}],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    labels: ['Total', 'Amount', 'Un'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
    xLabelAngle: 70
});});
```

I want the data from my JSON to be loaded in morris.js . Also,I dont want to touch the HTML Code. In the HTML code I am just calling  element from JS.
I read some related posts but was unable to link them as I am very new to Java scripting .

If I use the local JSON it works fine

```
$(function () {
var datajson='[{"x":"sales", "y":"46146","z":"46146","a":"46146"},    {"x":"swami", "y":"460104","z":"460104","a":"460104"}]';
var parsedContent = JSON.parse(datajson);
Morris.Bar({
 element: 'morris-bar-year',
 data: parsedContent,
 axes : true,
 xkey : 'x',
 ykeys : [ 'y', 'z', 'a' ],
 labels : [ 'Quotation amount ', 'Purchase order amount ', 'Invoice amount' ],
 barColors : [ 'red', 'blue', 'green' ]
 }); });
```

So now the question is how to call external JSON ?
Can you please help me with same ?

Regards

Comment: so the json is in an external file, is it server side?

Comment: Yes . I am using localhost:808/jsonpath/jsonfile.json

Comment: Make an ajax call - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried  that but I think I am not so good in it . Unable to get it done .